# Pandas DateTime Interpretation Issues & Plotting with axvline

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Recently I've used pd.to_datetime to assist with formatting date-time series data into the respective format I need for a matplotlib plot. I haven't had any issues until now where for an unknown reason, when I use a axvline (Matplotlib), a date-time error is thrown. However, this is **only** thrown when my code is executed in a function and not run in the console. After trying for the past two days, I've opted to ask this on SO for some guidance.

The expected output is:
[image: Expected output]
Where the dotted red-line indicates a singular failure date.

My function follows the logic below:

```
for i in result:

Asset_Num = i.strip(".csv")
dataframe = pd.read_csv(i)
df2 = dataframe[(dataframe['Asset_Number']==Asset_Num)]
#Convert the Date/Time object into a list of Time Stamp Values
fdl = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date/Time'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").to_list()
ax = dataframe.plot(linewidth=2)
ax.axvline(fdl, color='r', linestyle="--")
```

The error that is then thrown as I run this function is:
[image]

But I am confused as both the X-axis and fdl variable, both are in the same date-time format and I have checked this numerous times.

What am I doing wrong?

I've attached some sample data as per our minimum criteria guidelines if you'd like to try recreate this. (http://www.sharecsv.com/s/292b419dc674302ac5b6a96a2da0e06e/SampleData.csv)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post sample data ?

Comment: @XXavier Yep. I have added a link for your reference.

Comment: The date format you are using and the format in the data are different. I am not getting the same error when i tried to plot. What exactly you are trying to plot using those dates column? You want the date column as your x axis?

Comment: @XXavier I'm aware - the difference is how it is is imported into Python (as you can see from the screenshots and plots -it switches to the YY-MM-DD format). I am trying to plot the date/time where the Asset_Number has had a failure (I.e. The Asset_Number column shows 00037)

Comment: @XXavier The error you may see after this may then pop up as a date/time format error.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing wrong. I added some 00037 rows in the Asset_Number columns of your data and plotted those line like below and it worked for me.
`fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))`
`ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)`
`ax1.plot(df['Date/Time'], df['Pump Torque'])`
`for i, rw in df[df['Asset_Number']==37].iterrows():`
    `ax1.axvline(rw['Date/Time'], color='r', zorder=0)`

Comment: Here are the only two cleaning i did in your data. `df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
df.dropna(subset=['Date/Time'], inplace=True)`

Comment: @XXavier Hm, I'm still not convinced re: the root cause of the problem. Re: your approach - why don't you try creating another sample file (so you have at least two to iterate over), and try and see if you are able to plot this still? i.e. Modify the Sample File and replace 00037 with 00038 over a different failure time and see if you can still plot this.

Comment: You need to change this `ax.axvline(fdl, color='r', linestyle="--")` from `axvline` taking list to scalar value. You can see that i am only giving single date inside the `axvline`,
fdl is a list.

Comment: `for dt in fdl:
ax.axvline(dt, color='r', linestyle="--")`